# Check that all lines match regex pattern in Java

Tags: java, regex, pattern-matching

How to check that all lines match regex pattern in Java.

I mean that I be able to split lines myself in **while** loop. But is there any library or standard API, which implement this functionality?

**UPDATE** This is Ruby solution:

```
if text =~ /PATTERN/
```

Comment: What do you have so far?

Comment: Afaik there is no native method with this functionality. And why bother bringing in an entire library for a method that is at most 5 lines of code?

Comment: If it's only for 1 regex I think it would be more efficient to diy.
Else look at Cup and JFlex.

Comment: I have to use this code to check email quotation splitting, for expression like "**AK>> Bob> >**"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a utility method using [Guava](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/) that returns true if every line in the supplied text matches the supplied pattern:

```
public static boolean matchEachLine(String text, Pattern pattern){
    return FluentIterable.from(Splitter.on('\n').split(text))
                         .filter(Predicates.not(Predicates.contains(pattern)))
                         .isEmpty();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no standard API functionality I know of to do this, however, something like this is easy enough:

```
string.matches("(What you want to match(\r?\n|$))*+")
```

Usage:

```
String string = "This is a string\nThis is a string\nThis is a string";
System.out.println(string.matches("(This is a string(\r?\n|$))*+"));
```

`\r?\n` covers the most common new-lines.
`$` is end of string.
`(\r?\n|$)` is a new-line or the end of string.
`*+` is zero or more - but this is [a possessive qualifier](http://www.regular-expressions.info/possessive.html).

So the whole thing basically checks that every line matches `This is a string`.

If you want it in a function:

```
boolean allLinesMatch(String string, String regex)
{
  return string.matches("(" + regex + "(\r?\n|$))*+");
}
```

[Java regex reference](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html).

**Prime example of why you need a possessive qualifier:**

If you take the string `This is a string.` repeated a few times (34 times to be exact) but have the last string be `This is a string.s` (won't match the regex) and have `What you want to match` be `.* .* .*\\.`, you end up waiting a quite while with `*`.

[`*` example](https://ideone.com/iXaxhy) - runtime on my machine - more than **a few hours**, after which I stopped it.

[`*+` example](https://ideone.com/8JGkxG) - runtime on my machine - much less than **a second**.

See [Catastrophic Backtracking](http://www.regular-expressions.info/catastrophic.html) for more information.

Comment: This could be horribly inefficient.  Look up "catastrophic backtrack regex".

Comment: @StephenC Added a possessive qualifier and a nice little test case.

Answer (score 1):

This is one I use

```
public static boolean multilineMatches(final String regex, final String text) {
    final Matcher m = Pattern.compile("^(.*)$", Pattern.MULTILINE).matcher(text);
    final Pattern p = Pattern.compile(regex);
    while(m.find()) {
        if (!p.matcher(m.group()).find()) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```